# Coq proving nonsensical inductive property implication?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, logical-foundations

In IndProp.v from Logical Foundations we have the following inductive property:

```
Inductive nostutter {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | nos_nil : nostutter []
  | nos_one : forall x, nostutter [x]
  | nos_cons : forall x h l, nostutter (h :: l) -> (x <> h) -> (nostutter (x :: h :: l)).
```

Is it possible to solve this:

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
H : nostutter [] -> nostutter [x]
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

Presumably one would need some sort of discriminate or contradiction since `nostutter [] -> nostutter [x]` seems like it makes no sense, but I don't see anything that would allow me to make progress. Is it just not possible to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about the meaning of the implication. `nostutter [] -> nostutter [x]` is a perfectly reasonable hypothesis -- indeed, it is a *theorem*:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive nostutter {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | nos_nil : nostutter []
  | nos_one : forall x, nostutter [x]
  | nos_cons : forall x h l, nostutter (h :: l) -> (x <> h) -> (nostutter (x :: h :: l)).

Lemma not_goal {X} (x : X) : @nostutter X [] -> nostutter [x].
Proof. intros _; apply nos_one. Qed.
```

An implication `A -> B` says that we can prove `B` by proving that `A` is true. If we can prove `B` without additional hypotheses, as it is the case for `nostutter [x]`, then the implication holds trivially.

Comment: Does that mean that the example I provided, where `nostutter [] -> nostutter [x]` could we used to prove False is impossible?

Comment: Indeed. Deriving `False` from a hypothesis `H : P` means that `P` is a contradiction. As the above theorem shows, `nostutter [] -> nostutter [x]` is not contradictory.